# Where is 'MainMenu' in VS2019's toolbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, toolbox

I'm creating a C# Windows Form App project (which using .NET 3.1 LTS). When I open the from design, select the toolbox and search for MainMenu, it's not there.

[image: My toolbox]

I have found [this](http://ttps://stackoverflow.com/a/2778254/15365513) StackOverflow post about adding MainMenu to the toolbox, but when I select `Choose Items` and then add MainMenu to the toolbox, it said:

[image: Choose items]
[image: The error]

And the MainMenu still not there. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: [MainMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu) has been deprecated and removed, as clearly stated in the Docs. Use a MenuStrip instead. (Unrelated) If you're building a new WinForms app now, consider targeting .Net 5 instead of .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! I tried MenuStrips and it works really well!